# Trouble with finding geometric progression pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this system:
$$ b_2-b_1 = 18
$$
$$ b_4-b_3 = 162
$$

I have to find $b_1$ (the first element) and $q$ (common ratio). Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $bq-b = 18$ and $bq^3-bq^2 = 162$.

$$
162 = b(q^3-q^2) = (bq-b)q^2 = 18q^2$$

Comment: I don't get how (bq-b)*q^2 is = 18q^2?

Comment: Because $bq-b = b_2-b_1$ is given to be 18

Comment: I'm really grateful for answering me the dump question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write $b_2$ as $q·b_1$ etc.
$$
q·b_1 - b_1 = 18 \\
q^3b_1 - q^2b_1 = 162
$$
which is the same as
$$
q·b_1 - b_1 = 18 \\
q^2(q·b_1 - b_1) = 162
$$
or
$$
(q-1)b_1 = 18 \\
q^2(q-1)b_1 = 162
$$

This is now really easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  if the progression is 
$$
b_n = b_0 x^n
$$
then 
$$b_2 - b_1 = b_0 ( x^2 - x)$$
and
$$b_4 - b_3 = b_0 ( x^4 - x^3)$$

From those two statements, what is the ratio $\frac{b_2 - b_1}{b_4 - b_3}$?

And from the statement of the problem, what is that same ratio?

From this, you can find $x^2$, thus $|x|$, and given $x$ you can find $b_0$.

Notice that there are actually two different solutions to this problem, one with a negative ratio $x$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get what this b0 is? 
b1 should be the first element in the progression e.g
b1, b1*x, b1*x^2...